# Invert the sign of a non-negative floating-point number: Would std::copysign(x) make a difference than (-1)*x?

Tags: c++, floating-point

Let's say we would write a function that would return the inverse of a non-negative floating-point number `x`. Would the following two functions make a difference in the result (say rounding issues), if `x` is neither `NaN` nor `inf`?

```cpp
double invert_mul(double x) {
    return -1.0 * x;
}

double invert_copy(double x) {
    return std::copysign(x, -1.0);
}
```

Comment: I think they might return different results for `0.0`.

Comment: All these functions need to do is flip the most significant bit, so as long as optimizations are enabled and x is positive (including +0), they should be equivalent. That's the case for [GCC on x86-64, with -O2](https://godbolt.org/z/rjqdTv), at least.

Comment: The C++ standard is not strict about floating-point behavior; implementations do not necessary adhere to the rules of the IEEE-754 standard for floating-point arithmetic. I would not expect either of these to exhibit **rounding** issues; they should both produce exactly the mathematical negation of `x`. However, I would not expect all C++ implementations to produce −0 if `x` is +0. If they are conforming to IEEE-754, then they should. In floating-point formats that permit non-canonical representations, it is conceivable one function might return a canonical result while the other does not.

Comment: @LHLaurini are you saying that `gcc` optimizes the `-1.0 *` to be the same as `copysign`?  That's interesting and unexpected.

Comment: @MarkRansom Not the same, but similar. The multiplication becomes a xor and the copysign becomes an or. So, only equivalent if the sign bit is zero. However, since that's an implementation detail, it could change at any time and should, of course, not be relied upon.

Comment: Instead of `-1.0 * x`, you could also write just `-x` (but this should generate the same instruction(s), as well)

Comment: `-1.0 * x` may incur normalization of non-canonical  encodings with obscure `double` encodings yet  not a value change.  `copysign()` would not likely change a  non-canonical  encoding to a  canonical encoding

Comment: "Let's say we would write a function that would return the inverse of a non-negative floating-point number x" --> Why are negative values not considered?  Certainly the compiler does not use that restriction in these 2 functions.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm just trying to use a minimum example for demonstration. If `x` is allowed to be negative, I would have to add flow control to the second function.